# how to arrange quotes in this bash command

Tags: bash, quoting, echo

`my_cmd --attr1 $(($1-$2)) --attr2 $(($1-$2+$3)) --attr3 $(($2+1))`
I have this command and I would like to debug it (put it in `echo` and see how command will look like) but I am struggling with arranging quotes for which part to treat like literal and which treat like value

in the end I would like to have `echo` to print

```bsh
$> ./script 20 10 10
my_cmd --attr1 10 --attr2 20 --attr3 11
```

please help also adding some guide for quotes in bash would be very welcome

Answer (score 1):

In bash, just a single set of double-quotes around the whole thing is enough:

```
$ cat script
echo "my_cmd --attr1 $(($1-$2)) --attr2 $(($1-$2+$3)) --attr3 $(($2+1))"
$ ./script 20 10 10
my_cmd --attr1 10 --attr2 20 --attr3 11
```

Double quotes allow substitutions with `$`, single-quotes treat those as literals.